# Return index of minimum value in resultSet Array of Objects

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have a query which returns a resultSet like this
[5,3,4.5,6.7,2.4,8]

I am trying to get the index of the minimum value e.g 4 in the example above

I have tried to iterate over the result but it is an object array and it will not compare object with Double even if I cast to Double I still get "cannot convert object to Double error.

Here is what I have tried

```
Query totalQuery = em
                .createQuery("SELECT AVG(a.first)-"+first+",AVG(a.second)-    "+second+",AVG(a.third)-"+third+",AVG(a.fourth)-"+fourth+",AVG(a.fifth)-    "+fifth+",AVG(a.sixth)-"+sixth+",AVG(a.seventh)-"+seventh+") FROM Games a WHERE     a.username='name'");
        int num=1,index=0;
        double maxAvg=-99999;
        for(Object obj: totalQuery .getResultList().toArray()){
            if(index>maxAvg){
                maxAvg=(Double)obj;
                index=num;
            }
            holeNum++;
        }

        return index;
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Objectodouble{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj[] = {3.5,3.0, 5.6,7.8};
        double min=Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++){

            double value = Double.parseDouble(obj[i].toString());
            if( value < min)
                min = value;

        }

        System.out.println("Min: "+min);
    } 
}
```

---

First try to convert Object to String and then convert it into double using Double.parseDouble(String) then you would be able to compare it to double variable.

You might try to convert Object directly into double I think that was the problem you were facing.

Comment: I tried this but the conversion fails as obj is [[Ljava.lang.Object;@6533cb1b] it fails on the line
double value = Double.parseDouble(obj[i].toString();

Comment: I noticed the missing bracket from compiler but it fails on the double value = line as yours is a straight hardcoded object array but coming from a resultSet I think it is appearing differently

Comment: I just provided you an example of how u can cast object to double. As you mentioned it may work differently with your input.

Comment: Yes thanks but I am asking for object array returned from resultSet as in question which is different format as its [[1,2,3]]